# How to maintain unique List Before Saving To Database? - C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, collections

A simplified scenario:

- I have a `List<Foo>`.
- `Foo` has two properties **Description** (*string*), **IsFoo** (*bool*)

E.g:

```
var foos = new List<Foo>();
```

User can "add new Foo's" via textboxes, then on form submit i do this:

```
foos.Add(new Foo { Description = txtOne.Text, IsFoo = true });
foos.SaveToDb();
```

However, there are **multiple textboxes**, and if for example they type "FooBar" in textbox one, then "FooBar" in textbox two, i **do not want to show an error**, but i simply do not want to add them to the collection. (don't worry about the reason behind this, this is a simplified scenario).

I don't need to show anything to the UI, just when they submit the form, before persisting to the database i need to remove any duplicates (or prevent them from being added to the list in the first place).

What's the easiest/best way to do this? Dictionary perhaps?

I'm using C#4, LINQ, .NET 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `HashSet<Foo>`.

HashSets are unique, unordered collections.
Adding an element that already exists will silently do nothing.  (and return `false`)

Note that you **must** override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on the `Foo` class to compare by value.

Also note that hashsets are intrinsically unordered; if you care about insertion order, you can't use it.

---

Alternatively, you can use LINQ to check whether your list has a duplicate:

```
if (!foos.Any(f => f.Description == txtOne.Text))
    foos.Add(new Foo { Description = txtOne.Text, IsFoo = true });
```

Comment: Yeah the problem is "Foo" is actually a POCO used for persistence (not directly though), so i don't really want to add extra metadata to it (even if it's via a partial). The "alternative" would work - but i also have a repeater on the page, and i'm using `AddRange` to add the items, not sure how to apply `Any` to the `AddRange`.

Comment: I ended up putting your "alternative" into an extension method (and another for addrange), and calling that. Thanks.

Comment: @RPM: You would call `Where` to fitler the items you're adding and only pass ones that aren't already there.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on SLaks' answer, you could do something like this:

```
public class FooComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo> {
    public static readonly FooComparer Instance = new FooComparer();

    private FooComparer() { }

    public bool Equals(Foo a, Foo b) {
        if (a == null)
            return b == null;

        if (b == null)
            return false;

        // For case-sensitivity:
        return a.Description == b.Description;

        // For case-insensitivity:
        return String.Equals(a.Description, b.Description, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Foo obj) {
        // For case-sensitivity:
        return obj.Description.GetHashCode();

        // For case-insensitivity:
        return StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(obj.Description);
    }
}
```

Then store your items in a `HashSet<Foo>` like so:

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<Foo>(FooComparer.Instance);
hashSet.Add(new Foo() { ... });
```

With this code, if a second `Foo` object is added to the hashset and has an identical description as one already present in the hashset, the new object will simply not be added.

Comment: Man you have been *everywhere* lately, 183 answers in nine days, wonder if there is a badge for that. :)

Comment: You won't handle funny Unicode characters.  Instead, `return String.Equals(a.Description, b.Description, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` and `return StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(obj.Description)`.

Comment: @RPM1984: Yeah... rep-capped for the eight full days I've been here, most active new user last week by rep, and 7th most active user overall last week by rep.  I need to take a break or something.  Maybe go outside once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Distinct in linq?

This is VB (and not accurate as I've not got VS on this machine), but something along the lines of:

Dim ie as IEnumerable(of Foo) = From obj As Foo In Foo's Select obj Distinct

Then implent IEqualityComparer? - lookd like @cdhowie just answered....